# messen vs ausmessen

Tags: difference, verb

Is there any difference in meaning or usage between "ausmessen" and "messen" when they mean "to measure"? I can't see none from DWDS's definition of "[ausmessen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ausmessen)" ("eine Fläche, einen Raum messen"). Example expressions:

- einen Bauplatz, ein Grundstück, ein Feld, ein Zimmer, eine Kiste, einen Waggon, die Distanz messen/ausmessen

Comment: With others you can only `Kräfte messen`, never `Kräfte ausmessen`. With nouns (`Maß` vs. `Ausmaß`) the difference more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **messen** is used for processes in which the value of a certain **quantity** is determined:

- die Temperatur/ den Abstand/ die Spannung/ das Gewicht/ den Wohlstand etc. messen

  <sup>(to measure the temperature/ the distance/ the voltage/ the weight/ the prosperity etc.)</sup>

The verb **ausmessen** is used to quantify (the area of) **a surface** or (the volume of) **a room**, typically by repeated use of a tool:

- den Tisch/ den Garten/ die Wohnstube/ den Kontainer etc. ausmessen

  <sup>(to measure the table [area]/ the garden [area]/ the living room [volume]/ the container [volume] etc.)</sup>

With *ausmessen*, I usually envision someone putting a folding ruler or a tape measure on all dimensions of the item in question and then doing some calculations.

Comment: Additionally, I'd argue that "messen" is used when referring to the actual quantity ("das Raumvolumen messen"), whereas "ausmessen" is used when referring to the object of which a certain quantity is to be measured ("das Haus ausmessen")

Comment: @Sentry, in fact, I had thought about adding a sentence like that as a summary, but then I decided not to do so, because I found it trivial.

Answer (score 1):

"Messen" is **one** value (e.g. temperature, height...)

"Ausmessen" is mainly used for measuring **multiple** dimensions (measure a area/room)

Comment: Would "die Distanz ausmessen" be wrong/unusual?

Comment: This is unusual, there you will be say "die Distanz *messen* zwischen Punkt A und Punkt B". *Ausmessen* you need for measuring as example your room, that you know how big your bed can be. "Ich muss mein Zimmer ausmessen, damit ich weiß wie groß mein Bett sein kann"

Comment: Man auch mehrere Werte *messen*, weshalb der erste Satz falsch ist. Doch selbst wenn er richtig wäre, taugt er nicht zur Abgrenzung von *ausmessen*, denn auch beim Ausmessen erhalte ich unter Umständen nur einen Wert, zum Beispiel für das Volumen eines ausgemessenen Zimmers. Zudem sind Temperatur und Höhe keine Werte, sondern Größen.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue, that the difference can be compared to the difference between *trinken* and *austrinken* (i. e. drink until the glass is empty) and *diskutieren* vs. *ausdiskutieren* (discuss until no new arguments appear and an agreement is reached): *Ausmessen* is to measure all relevant data.

In case of a room this may exceed length and width (which would be sufficient for a new carpet), since position of the door and windows may also have an impact when positioning furniture. For calculation of the amount of paint needed for the walls, the height is also needed etc.

For something as simple as a distance, where a single number results, *ausmessen* seems somewhat exaggerated, but not exactly wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say intuitively that *ausmessen* is a hyponym that works only for spacial measurements.  That concerns primarily areas and volumes, which are always interiors of some boundary -- hence the `aus-` präfix.  But you can also use it for length (between to points).  Note that it doesn't have to be a measurement with a ruler: *Ich kann kann das Volumen der Vase mit Wasser ausmessen*.

Now to the stranger DWDS examples:

> Die Modems messen jede Verbindung aus und ermitteln so das jeweils passende Übertragungsverhalten.

This is talking about data rates, I guess, but it can be conceptualized as a measurement of flow between two endpoints, which you can also legitimately use *ausmessen* for.  From this (and, again, my intuition), I conclude that *ausmessen* is also used for values distributed over space, or "gradients" between spacial boundaries: *Temperaturverteilung auf einer Fläche ausmessen*, *Spannung zwischen zwei Punkten ausmessen*.

The difference to the prototypical case is that there, the space is typically the grammatical object (*ich messe das Zimmer aus* = its size), while in the conceptualized variant, the measured value is (*ich messe die Temperaturverteilung aus*).  Except of course when you are already talking about the kind of value you measure; then *das Zimmer ausmessen* can mean to measure the value in focus within the room (heat distribution, voltage between all appliances, etc.).

> Der Maler, das erkannte man, maß die Stelle zwischen den Augen aus, wo die Axt auftreffen sollte.

A completely different sense of the same term: it means to estimate a location, or a target (a somewhat similar metaphor to *abwägen*).  This is a rather antiquated, or at least literary, usage.

Comment: Your second example is pretty disturbing + confusing and I don't know if it's even right ^^

Comment: @mtwde Which one? The quoted examples are both from DWDS, which the OP linked to, I just commented on them (and the second quote is from _Deutschstunde_, which IIRC _is_ somewhat disturbing).

Comment: Without context you don't know, why a "Maler" should use an "Axt" and why he (as a painter) wants to kill someone/something with it.